# Get the innermost element of a tree in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an app which prints out the exceptions similar to the below

```
<Exception>
    <Exceptions>
        <Exception>
            <Desc>something</Desc>
            <Exceptions>
                <Exception>
                    <Desc>something else</Desc>
                    <Exceptions>
                        <Exception>
                            <Desc>Most Important Exception</Desc>
                        </Exception>
                    </Exceptions>
                </Exception>
            </Exceptions>
        </Exception>
    </Exceptions>
</Exception>
```

I am after the "Most Important Exception" using an xpath.

I tried `//node()[not(node())]` but it doesn't just give me the most inner node.

Comment: These days the current version of XSLT is 3.0 and not 2.0 and all supported versions of e.g. Saxon are XSLT 3 processor; as XSLT 3.0 supports the XPath 3 function `innermost` I on wonder whether you can't simply use it e.g. `innermost(//*)` gives you the three leaf elements (e.g. `Desc`) and `sort(innermost(//*), (), function($el) { count($el/ancestor::*) })[last()]` the one that is most deeply nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 (XPath)**

```
//*[not(*) and not(parent::*/*/*)]/text()
```

explanation:

`//*` : any element

`[not(*) and not(parent::*/*/*)]` : not having a child-element and non having a parent that has a deeper structure than to me as element.

Since `parent::*/*` is on the same level as the context-element, `parent::*/*/*` is one level deeper. If that's `not()` the case, we have the innermost element.

`/text()` : it's text-node

**Option 2 (XPath)**

```
//*[not(*) and not(following-sibling::*)]/text()
```

explanation:

`//*` : any element

`[not(*) and not(following-sibling::*)]` : not having a child-element and non having a following-sibling

`/text()` : it's text-node

**Option 3 (XPath)**

probably the most explicit and understandable :

```
//Exception[not(Exceptions)]/Desc/text()
```

explanation:

`//Exception` : any Exception-element

`[not(Exceptions)]` : not having a child-Exceptions-element

`/Desc/text()` : the text-node of it's child-Desc element

**Option 4 (xslt)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group group-by="count(ancestor::*)" select="//*[not(*)]">
      <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::*)" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <xsl:sequence select="text()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will select all deepest text-nodes by first grouping them by there ancestor-count.

All options will select optional more than one text-node, depending if there are more deepest nodes.

Comment: Options 1 is working for me. Why is "not(parent::*/*/*)" mentioning 3 levels specifically? Understand the idea is to not have a parent having at a lower level which has deeper structure.. but not able to wrap my head around it.

Comment: The first * in parent::* is the parent. The second * in parent::*/* is a child of the parent like the current element. So the third * in parent::*/*/* is an element deeper than the current element.